# What's the meaning of idioms "school in" and "get something into bones"

Tags: idioms

1. School in:
   I searched for it on the internet but couldn't find its meaning or anything related to it. I found this idiom in a past year question paper. [image: 6th-part]
2. Get something into bones:
   I found this idiom in essay "First year at harrow" by Winston Churchill. [Here is link to pdf version of essay.](http://www.hsomnibus.com/readroom/harrow.pdf)

   > Thus, **I got into my bones** the essential structure of the ordinary
   >   British sentence -- which is a noble thing.

[image: Page 2/5]
I inferred from it that he learned the essential structure of english thoroughly, but I couldn't find any such idiom on the internet.

Comment: Please transcribe the relevant parts of the text in the images. Text in images is not searchable.

Answer (score 2):

*To school in* is an expression meaning to teach or train, generally a skill or craft.

It is frequently used in the passive to mean that someone had acquired skills:

> > He was schooled in the craft of stone-masonry.

It can also be used actively:

> > The poacher schooled his children in the art of catching birds.

The Oxford Dictionary defines schooled as: Educated or trained in a specified activity or in a particular way.

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/schooled)